# Selenium Python scrape <td> element returns blank text

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to extract the year 2016 (shown in a red box in the picture). I have tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class = 'zsg-table yui3-toggle-content-minimized']/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]")
```

but it only returns a blank text.

[image: html source screenshot]

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

To extract the `text` (year) **2016** you can use the following line of code :

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='zsg-table yui3-toggle-content-minimized' and starts-with(@id,'yui_')]//tbody/tr/td").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

Comment: It does returns a text, but not the year (2016). Here is the link I tried to scrape the data from (https://www.zillow.com/homes/recently_sold/Upson-County-GA/70442366_zpid/779_rid/globalrelevanceex_sort/33.02536,-84.05056,32.66828,-84.606743_rect/10_zm/). The information I want to scrape is the first line of the Tax History. I could scrape the tax amount and assessment with no problem but currently struggle to get the tax year.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this XPATH :- `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class ='zsg-table yui3-toggle-content-minimized']//td[text()='2016']")`

Comment: I think the objective of OP is to extract the year. This implies that he **doesn't know** the text. So `//td[text()='2016']` won't help him/her in a general case.

Comment: @KeyurPotdar is right. Hard code asking for the year 2016 wouldn't help me. Here is the link I tried to scrape the data from (zillow.com/homes/recently_sold/Upson-County-GA/70442366_zpi‌​d/…). The information I want to scrape is the first line of the Tax History. I could scrape the tax amount and assessment with no problem but currently struggle to get the tax year.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why my code returns a blank text. It's because the table I was scraping was not the Tax History table, it was Price History instead. Once I changed this, my code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one will work:

```
year = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class = 'zsg-table yui3-toggle-content-minimized']/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]')
```

If year:

```
year= year[0].text.strip()
```